# UIPageView UIWebView Prefetch

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I am making an app with the UIPageViewController. Right now I just have a UIWebView in each page. Right now I run `[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];` inside viewWillAppear. It works ok but there is a lag when the page will show up as the http request is sent out right when the gesture recognizer handles the event for the page flip.

I tried writing some code inside

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

but I couldn't get it to work.

Whats a good way to prefetch the UIWebView for next page before flipping to make the page show up instantly when page is being flipped?

Answer (score 0):

Create two web views, one displayed in your view, one offscreen. Whenever you need to move from page to page, start loading your new content into the offscreen one and in `viewWillAppear:` add the offscreen webview to your view hierarchy. Finally, in the previous view controller's `viewDidDisappear:` call `removeFromSuperview` on what was your previous web view. Now the original is your offscreen web view.

Remember that these web views should be shared between all your views (and view controllers), so they should be in a shared location.